# Create Powerpoint Shape with Hyperlink in same document

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have found this code to create a shape and to add a hyperlink, which I modified to have the hyperlink go to another slide in the same document, but get compile error at Actionsettings.

```
Sub Hyper()
Dim pr As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sl As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
Set pr = ActivePresentation
Set sh = sl.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)
sh.ActionSettings (ppMouseClick)
    .Hyperlink.Address = ""
    .SubAddress = "257,2,"
    .ScreenTip = ""
    .TextToDisplay = "My Name"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the compile error occurs? What is the exact wording of the message? A hyperlink on a shape will not display any text, so TextToDisplay is not going to do anything. What is a SubAddress of _257,2,_ supposed to do? Normally this would be the slide title of the slide to which you want to jump.

Comment: `SubAddress` is a property of `Hyperlink`, not of an `ActionSetting`

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Williams said, `SubAddress` is a property of `Hyperlink`

```
Sub Hyper()
Set pp = ActivePresentation

Set sh = pp.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=100, Height:=200)
With sh.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = pp.Slides(2).SlideNumber 'Hyperlink to Slide Number
End With

End Sub
```